# What happens technically when a Sqlite database is corrupted and how to detect?

Tags: database, sqlite, corruption

I am doing a task of handling database corruption, so I have been through SQLite's [How to corrupt an SQLite database](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html) and SO's [How to verify if a database file is valid/consistent](https://serverfault.com/questions/8048/how-can-i-verify-that-a-sqlite-db3-file-is-valid-consistent).

But I have more specific questions, which might help others also. Boolean answers are OK

1. If a sqlite database file is corrupted will I be able to open it? Sometimes or always?
2. If answer1 is yes and I open it, can read/write operations crash my application or will simply return error which can be handled?
3. If corruption happens, can some of my following(next) read/writes succeed or every read/write will return error?
4. Can after successfully creating and closing a database file, I use `md5sum` to detect any corruption in the next opening of file, provided I want to avoid `quick_check` and `integrity_check` as they are slower?

Comment: Please define the word "corruption" in this context. Yes, I do know the traditional meaning of the word but I need to know which concepts you pack into the word in the context of this question.

Answer (score 6):

The very nature of corrupted data is that unless you run a thorough verification process, all bets are off. Anything can happen. Pigs can fly. Who knows.

Answers to your questions:

1. Sometimes, yes. Since SQLite does not verify the entire database when you open it, there is no way for it to know that the file is corrupt unless it happens to read the corrupt data during opening.
2. Most likely crashing operations will crash in a way that you can handle. If there are exploitable bugs in SQLite, like buffer overrun bugs or similar, then all bets are off but there is no indication that such things exists.
3. Some can work, some can fail, there is no way to know beforehand.
4. You cannot detect a corrupt SQLite database using MD5. For starters, what should the correct MD5 value be? The only way to know would be to calculate it from the file, which is what you would do to verify as well.

In short, short of executing `pragma integrity_check;` periodically, you have no guarantees for how SQLite will handle a corrupted database.

As an example, what if the corruption happen to make the database look valid, except that it no longer contains the original data the user stored in it?

Comment: Thanks. Got it. But for the last question(4), if I closed the DB file successfully and I know till closing there was no problem, if anything wrong happens to the file while it was lying dormant, `md5sum` will change and I can say corruption happened.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I would personally focus more on what happened to the file and how to prevent that than to detect the corruption. Why this fear of data corruption?